# Setup youtube API v3 for PHP

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I want to use YouTube API version 3 for php. I download samples for php from GitHub.

On the YouTube API in google console and replace the `DEVLOPER_KEY` in sample files. Then I see in every file there is two file include `Google/Client.php` and `Google/Service/YouTube.php`.

These two files are not in the sample folder which I download so, I search on google and download google client library for php. Then I run the sample file and it show error.

> Fatal error: Class `Google_Service` not found in `D:\wamp\www\api\php\Google\Service\YouTube.php` on line 32

What is the problem can I not download every thing correctly I miss any thing? Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Just include the [`autoload.php`](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/autoload.php) in your projects and you should be fine.

Comment: you need to `include()` or `require()` the client.php and youtube.php files.

Comment: @brian I already include client.php and youtube.php

Comment: @jan I include `autoload.php` it give error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.' in D:\wamp\www\api\php\Google\autoload.php on line 14`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be looking for a simple video search on YouTube API so best approach code is given below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$search = "Search Query"; // Search Query

$api = "YouTube API Key"; // YouTube Developer API Key

$link = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?safeSearch=moderate&order=relevance&part=snippet&q=".urlencode($search). "&maxResults=10&key=". $api;

$video = file_get_contents($link);

$video = json_decode($video, true);

foreach ($video['items'] as $data){
        $title = $data['snippet']['title'];
        $description = $data['snippet']['title'];
        $vid = $data['id']['videoId'];
        $image = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/$vid/default.jpg";

        // Output Title/Description/Image URL If Video ID exist
        if($vid){
            echo "Title: $title<br />Description: $description<br />Video ID: $vid<br />Image URL: $image<hr>";
        }
}
?>
```